# How do I create an Xcode project from Qt code?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, qmake

I've been using

```
qmake -spec macx-xcode
```

to generate an Xcode project, which compiles a Qt code that I have.

However, this command populates the project file with absolute file paths. This means if I put the project somewhere else, it will fail to build as all the file paths are still pointing to where the project was.

Is there a way to convert this to use relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Comment: I think in general when you deal with generated code/projects, the best thing to do is re-generate them when you move them around.

Comment: qmake generates make/build files to build locally, not a "proper", portable XCode build system one would share, which is probably created most easily from scratch within XCode. When using qmake, the shared build files are the qmake files, not the make/project files it creates.